# Ubercart get order id from custom field value

Tags: entities, ubercart

I have created a custom field for using Drupal Field module. I want to get order if from the value of that custom field id. group_number_oc is the name of the custom field which stores 2,4 etc numbers. I want to get order or orders which has group_number_oc value equal to 2 or 4 or any dynamic value.

Is there any way?

Similarly there is a custom field group_number_usr for users as well. and I want to get all the users that have custom field value equal to 1, 2 etc.

Custom field name for users and orders have different name (Note).

Comment: After some R&D I found

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
 $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'uc_order_product')
 ->fieldCondition('field_field_group_number_or', 'value', '1' , '=');
$result = $query->execute();
print_r($result);

But I get empty result. I have checked in the admin area of ubercart for order entity type, the values is present for this custom field for few orders.

Any suggestion?